# Why dismiss is calling delegate many times?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I just willing to send data back to the parent view controller.
I try to implement with delegate with my second view controller.

```
protocol SendDataDelegate {
    func sendData(data: String)
}

delegate?.sendData(data: metadataObj.stringValue!)
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However parent view controller get the data more over 16 times.
How can I prevent more over 2 times?

Comment: This will never send it back more than once, add your code where you are sending `sendData` that is for some reason being called more than once.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent"? Are you willing to make it get called only for the first attempt instead of each time popping from the second view controller? Where are you calling `delegate?.sendData(data: metadataObj.stringValue!)`?

Comment: This is a question for your debugger. Set a breakpoint on `sendData` and see what's happening. Is the data being sent the same every time? Is `sendData` always sent by the same object? Is `sendData` only called in one place, or is it called in several places? Dig in and figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked for possible retain cycles? I'm just guessing but maybe you established a strong reference to your delegate.